# difference between java-6-openjdk-i386 and java-7-openjdk-i386

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, java

I wanted to upgrade my java version and i was using `java-6-openjdk-i386`. So, i decided to upgrade it to `java-7-openjdk-i386`. After i installed it i jave surprise to see no java in the jre/bin folder. why is it so? I am attaching the screenshots of both the folder below :

[image: listing of java-6-openjdk-i386 folder]

[image: listing of java-7-openjdk-i386 folder]

Also, when i use `java -version` command what does `IcedTea6 1.13.8` signify?

```
java version "1.6.0_36"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.8) (6b36-1.13.8-0ubuntu1~12.04)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Since there is no java in jre folder. So, any suggestions how i upgrade the java version on `ubuntu 12.04`

Comment: Did you check whether there is `java` in the `bin` directory directly under `java-7-openjdk-i386`?

Comment: No, there is no java in the bin folder also.

Comment: So you don't seem to have actually installed Java 7 properly. You may have installed a package that only contains the security stuff. Check your package manager for *all* java packages. You can also opt for installing the Oracle Java instead of OpenJDK.